# Burninate the "plugins" tag

Tags: feature-request, retag-request

[plugins](/questions/tagged/plugins) seems to be a meta tag. Can it go?

> A plug-in (or plugin) is a set of software components that adds specific abilities to a larger software application. If supported, plug-ins enable customizing the functionality of an application.

Some examples of tags shared by things tagged with [plugins](/questions/tagged/plugins):

- plugins jenkins environment-variables starteam
- android eclipse plugins installation
- wordpress plugins jscrollpane
- asp.net asp.net-mvc plugins iis-express
- cakephp plugins
- jquery css plugins gallery
- java pdf plugins reader viewer
- plugins crm retrieve
- plugins npapi createprocess firebreath
- visual-studio plugins

These are the tags for the top ten questions in [plugins](/questions/tagged/plugins) at the time of this writing. Clearly none of these questions are similar to each other at all. I move to burninate.

**Questions that need retagging:**

- Questions about the design pattern (plugin pattern) should be tagged [plugin-pattern](/questions/tagged/plugin-pattern). Questions about plugin development should be tagged [plugin-development](/questions/tagged/plugin-development).
- Questions about plugins for a specific platform should be tagged with the appropriate tag for that platform, for example [jquery-plugins](/questions/tagged/jquery-plugins) or [eclipse-plugin](/questions/tagged/eclipse-plugin).
- Questions about plugin development for a particular platform should be retagged with the appropriate tag, for example [wordpress-plugin-dev](/questions/tagged/wordpress-plugin-dev).

For the sake of completeness:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would dispute this burnination as plugin is a [valid architectural pattern](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/plugin.html). It may have been used incorrectly and need a tidy up, but extermination is too far.

*Just to be totally pedantic, while the **plugin** pattern is singular, I believe most people when talking about it will use the plural form of the word. I wouldn't advocate a synonym as they do have slightly different contexts, therefore the best bet may be a tag tidy up - if it is enough of a problem.*

Comment: Can you find any questions that are using the `plugins` tag in this way? Note the plurality, `plugin` is an alias for `plugins`. Also note the tag wiki (added to the question). A new tag, `plugin-pattern`, could be created. This would be in line with [tag:observer-pattern], for instance.

Comment: @GGG - I just came back and edited my answer in regards to that - before I even saw your comment, funny that :)

Comment: I've added a "Questions that need retagging" section to my question :)